# Synchronization of run() method

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Process extends Thread {

   private static int count=0;

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
       for (int i=0; i< 1000000000; i++)
              count++;
   } }
```

Consider the above snippet. If more threads of type Process are running, this code is not thread-safe due to the cuncurrent access to the static variable.

How to make this code "thread safe"?

Is it an option to enclose `count++` within a `static synchronized` method and invoking this instead?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Comment: `1 000 000 000` is not a valid integer literal. Use `1000000000` or `1_000_000_000`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You better use a builtin `synchronized` accumulator like [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

```
 AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

 for (int i=0; i< 1000000000; i++)
      count.incrementAndGet();
```

Another accumulator that comes with Java 8 is the [LongAdder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html) which gives a higher throughput under high contention at the expense of more space

```
 LongAdder longAdder = new LongAdder();

 for (int i=0; i< 1000000000; i++)
    longAdder.increment();

 System.out.println(longAdder.sum());
```

`AtomicInteger` and `locks` are great for concurrent access but if `parallelism` is what you trying to achieve then give [LongAccumulator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAccumulator.html) and [LongAdders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html) a look, they should scale better on multi-core

Answer (score 2):

Use [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of `int`, or perform the critical work under synchronization:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();

...

synchronized(lock) {
  count++;
}
```